# Where is stdlib implemented in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, dll, stdio

In what .dll file are the `stdio` functions implemented? I want to test my stack-language's FFI with basic c functions, but I cannot seem to find the correct .dll to `GetModuleHandle`, to then get function addresses with `GetProcAddress`...

Comment: That will depend on what environment you are using to build and run your code.  Some environments bag all the library code into one big .dll, while others split it many .dlls.  What environment are you using?

Comment: @ryyker by "environment", do you mean something like MinGW/MSVC++?

Comment: Yes, I am putting a link below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating Windows apps, and want a complete set of libraries for accessing these functions, download the Windows SDK ***[HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)***

I always keep a copy on my dev machine.  There are all kinds of things that come up with Windows programming that just require having access to Microsoft's highly monopolized interfaces to its overly burdensome OS :)

The Microsoft redistributable libraries:  msvcr80.dll. msvcr100.dll et al. contain the functionality you are asking about, and as the name implies, are redistributable.

Comment: So stdio functions aren't implemented in, say, `kernel32.dll` or `user32.dll`?

Comment: msvcr100.dll is the 64 bit (one of many) redistributable lib for microsoft.  msvcr80.dll is one I have used for 32 bit.  <strike>_Both_<\strike> Correction, these come with version SDK, depending on version.  And are also separately downloadable.  I do not know about the kernel32, or user32.dlls per se.  Ha, ha, I cannot get my html to work right, but you get the idea?

Comment: Thanks! `msvcr100.dll` contains all of the functions that I want. I'll create an answer to that effect, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Your welcome.  I will add that to my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the system dll `msvcrt.dll` which is installed in the system32 directory and is part of the Windows system so you won't need to worry about redistribution - it's just there.  `msvcrt.dll` is the DLL that MinGW uses as it's base runtime.

Comment: Does `msvcrt.dll` contain all of the stdio functions? If so, why are the functions implemented in more than one .dll?

Comment: @feralin - Evidently, it does.  ***[LOOK HERE](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65238)*** for a blog entry for some issues discussing use of printf etc.  Michael Burr's answer is a good one.  Although at work I use commercial compilers, so I have to distribute the Microsoft redistributables with some of my projects there, but at home, sometimes I use minGW, but did not even think about which .dll it used.

Comment: @Michael - Very useful to know.  In fact, I should have :)

Comment: Keep in mind that third-party use of `msvcrt.dll` is only technically supported for code compiled with Visual Studio 6, and is not supported at all for 64-bit code.  It's a common enough practice, and it mostly works, but there may be some unexpected edges here and there.